# How to Enable Universal Mirror Repo (E: Unable to locate package xyz)

Tags: mirrors

I was running into issues trying to install the third party software gtypist. The error present was:

```
E: Unable to locate package xyz
```

Suggestions on updating mirror environment would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) . Also see https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=gtypist .

Answer (score 0):

Third party software can be installed from universal mirror. However, be careful as Ubuntu doesn't ensure regular security checks.

To check if you have universal mirror enabled enter:

```
apt policy | grep "universe"
```

You can then enable universe mirror by entering:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
```